# usage of the word "such"

Tags: such

I’m not sure whether this sentence is correct or not,
“The man turned his computer on and covered his eyes, such was the light emitted from the screen.” or "such powerful was the light emitted from the screen."

I know that I could say:
“Such was the light emitted from the screen, that …”

But my question is, can I put the part of the sentence with “such” at the end, as the first example?

Thanks

Comment: Except for *such powerful,* which should be *so powerful,* these are all grammatical. They're very elegantly constructed, and are quite at home in writing, but would sound a bit off in casual speech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason you can't use a constructor like 'such' mid-way through a sentence, so it is correct to use:

> “The man turned his computer on and covered his eyes, such was the light emitted from the screen.”

However it is not valid to say:

> “The man turned his computer on and covered his eyes, such powerful was the light emitted from the screen.”

You would instead phrase it:

> “The man turned his computer on and covered his eyes, so powerful was the light emitted from the screen.”

This is because you use 'so' in front of an adjective like 'powerful', instead of 'such'.

You can find more details here:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/such-or-so